# when c# program crash how to know why?

Tags: c#

Often my program crash by some reason. In this case I do see Windows message with "Close" button. Every time such thing happen I do really want to know what happened.

Thanks to community I already know how to "handle" some situations, I've added such code in the beggining of my program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException +=
        (object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs excArgs) =>
        {
            Log.Push(LogItemType.Error, "Exception occured. Task terminated! + " + excArgs.Exception);
            excArgs.SetObserved();
        };

    .....

    static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: CurrentDomain_UnhandledException entered.");
        string message = (e.ExceptionObject as Exception).Message;
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(message, "Unhandled UI Exception");
        Log.Push(LogItemType.Error, message);
    }
```

Sometimes this helps. But sometimes program just crash with no message. What else can I do? Every time program crash I want to know why.

**upd** Windows Logs contains almost everything I need, except the most important thing - the stacktrace

```
Faulting application name: MBClient.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x50a5da1d
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17725, time stamp: 0x4ec4aa8e
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000c40f2
Faulting process id: 0x10f8
Faulting application start time: 0x01cdc3c2041e2607
Faulting application path: C:\Oleg\bin\mbclient\MBClient.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 810c805d-2fc3-11e2-bfb5-2c768a509157
```

Comment: Had you tried to use a debugger (VS debugger/WinDbg/OllyDbg/etc.)?

Comment: do you have any logging in your program so that you can pinpoint to some extent where the problem is?

Comment: Your `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException` method is throwing away useful information. Exception objects hold many useful properties, especially `StackTrace` which tells you *where* the exception originated from.

Comment: @AlvinWong i run program on production machine. I can install something, but i don't want to install a lot of stuff. it supposed to be "clean" machine with no addition software

Comment: @Default i have many threads. and I almost don't log anything in "normal" run, because logging is too expensive for HFT trading application. I do log only when "troubleshooting", i can't "always" use logs

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so far CurrentDomain_UnhandledException was never occured in my program. So I just don't know how useful it for me. But UnobservedTaskException occcurs sometimes.

Comment: there should be some usefull info in your systems eventlog - there won't be any stacktrace or such but the type of exception should be there

Comment: Have you tried looking in the Windows Event Log on the computer concerned? Often application crash information is logged here, under Applications, too, depending on the type.

Comment: @dash yes event log has entry for crash. but there are no exception in this entry. only stuff like that `Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17725, time stamp: 0x4ec4aa8e`

Comment: Maybe you catched an `AggregateException`. Then its stack trace is NULL and you have to extract it from the inner list of aggregated exceptions. Additionally there are also other useful callbacks. For both look to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77188451/789423).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Exception code 0xc0000374 means you're facing *heap corruption*.

The most common causes for this kind of error are these two:

- A faulty RAM module
- Buffer overrun, when one thread tries to read something and another thread has removed data in the meanwhile. This shouldn't happen in managed code as far as I can tell.

You probably have to get [Windows Debugging Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx) to figure out what's wrong if you can't debug the application in the dev environment.

Comment: regarding seconds point - i want to log "production" application which is not supposed to be run under debugger. Regarding first point - are you sure that every time program crash you will receive some exception?

Comment: There is no way to tell if this will actually help you, it usually does for me but 99.9% of my blowups are due to unexpected user behavior, which might apply to your case or not. I suggest you save yourself some time and swearing and go straight back to the dev environment, build a "staging" release with lots of logging, repro, and finally use the collected info to fix the code.

Comment: when exception occurs in main thread i do see it in console window. So it is not required to catch exception yourself, you will see it in console windows anyway.

Comment: I ditched and rewrote my answer for a more relevant one.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I came here after googling the exception code 0xc0000374.

There is an update available for the MS Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable package that fixes a heap corruption bug in the MS Visual C++ 2013 redistributable package.

Note: This update is (at time of writing) not being distributed through Windows Update.
Note 2: Obviously, this update will only help, if you are using a library compiled with MS VC++ 2013 (like in my case: the MySQL ODBC Connector 5.3.x)

The update link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3138367/update-for-visual-c-2013-and-visual-c-redistributable-package

And the source that pointed me to this update: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86054

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the WER  - Microsofts Windows Error Reporting for that. It is per default on every system. So e.g. you can do an automatic dump instead of the windows popup message.
There are a number of settings in the group policy editor.
see the following links
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: what about "Applications that do their own custom crash reporting, including .NET applications, are not supported by this feature." ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

I use unmanaged memory.
So the most simple way to REPRODUCE this bug is:

```
var DataPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1000 * sizeof(int));//asign a pointer for 1000 integers
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

If you try this you'll get:

```
The program '[12579] MyDemo.exe' has exited with code -1073740940 (0xc0000374).
```

So if you use such code [Alloc\Free] you might have copied some pointer to already released memory and later on release it, after it's already released.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Is there any way to get a stack trace when the application crashes this way?

Comment: Just to answer my own comment above: I was able to get the CLR call stack by using [WinDbg Preview](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windbg-preview/9PGJGD53TN86). When the application crashes, enter !clrstack in the WinDbg command line.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to obtain a CLR call stack by using [WinDbg Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412672/when-c-sharp-program-crash-how-to-know-why).

1. Install and launch WinDbg Preview
2. Through the file menu, launch the application executable (may have to click the "Go" button in WinDbg if the application doesn't launch immediately)
3. Perform some actions in the application that would trigger the ntdll.dll crash
4. (Optional) If you have .pdb files available, enter `.symfix <path to folder containing pdb files>` in the WinDbg command line
5. Enter `!clrstack` in the WinDbg command line (you can also use `!dumpstack` to get a more detailed view).

You should now see the full CLR call stack in the WinDbg output window, which should give you an indication of which part of your code caused the ntdll.dll crash.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error because of this:

```
var pointer = NativeMemory.AlignedAlloc(size, 32);
NativeMemory.Free(pointer)  // <-- Emm, maybe AlignedFree??No??Okay, suffer!
```

Now I changed the code and seems like it works stable! I need more time to prove it, actually.

Answer (score -3):

Just use [try catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) at "risky" parts of your code where you think it could crash.

Comment: ... yeah let's 'catch(Exception)' everywhere ... not - no really: don't do if you don't know how to handle the exception

Comment: Since javapowered doesn't want to log because it's too expensive for him I supposed this method where he could log when only an error occured. But surly this method needs knowledge about what exception(s) can occur when and how do you need to handle it

Comment: 0xc0000374 is not a managed exception, but an error in C/C++ code, which will cause an immediate application hard crash, and none of the managed exception handling code, neither `try/catch`, nor event subscription to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` will be called