# Get the actual StackTrace object from an Exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, stack-trace

An `Exception` object has a `StackTrace` property on it.  But it is just a string.

**Is there a way to get an actual `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` object from an `Exception`?**

I ask because I am getting the Exception object from an `UnhandledExceptionEventHandler` and I don't have access to the frame that generated the exception to get an actual Stack Trace.

Comment: Using some of the `StackTrace` [constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25h0kw08(v=vs.110).aspx) with `Exception` argument? e.g. `new StackTrace(ex)`.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479762/exception-with-no-stack-trace-how) question seems related; if true your stack trace is gone already and you need to fix any `throw ex` calls. Note that if this is the case, then @IvanStoev's answer shouldn't work because the `ex` is already missing the stack trace so I don't think the `StackTrace` constructor will find anything to copy. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383/in-c-how-can-i-rethrow-innerexception-without-losing-stack-trace) for how to re-throw an exception without losing the stack trace in .NET 4.5+.

Comment: @Quantic - thank you for the response, but PALMERALE's and IvenStoev's solution seems to work great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try{
//some code
}
catch (Exception ex){
   System.Diagnostics.StackTrace stackTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly!  Adding `, true` after the `ex` gets you the file info too!