# Ole Db communication works in powershell not in c#

Tags: c#, powershell, oledb

Im trying to receive information from an ABB 800xa historian via Ole Db HDA. I have a working script in powershell but when i do the same in a C# visual studio console app project i get an exit code 0xc0000374.

What could be the difference between the Powershell script and my c# code?
P.s.: In C# the connection via Ole Db works and some commands do work but some don't

My Powershell script:

```
clear-host
$objConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection ("Provider=ABB OLE DB Provider for HT;Persist Security Info=False;User ID="";Data Source="";Location="";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=""")
$sqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("GET_HISTORY(OBJECTHELPER=History Log Template Dion)")
$sqlCommand.Connection = $objConn
$objConn.open()
write-host $sqlCommand.CommandText
$reader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
$Counter = $Reader.FieldCount
while ($Reader.Read()) {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Counter; $i++) {
        @{ $Reader.GetName($i) = $Reader.GetValue($i); }
    }
}
$reader.Close()
$sqlCommand.Dispose()
$objConn.close()
$objConn.Dispose()
```

My C# code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            OleDbConnection cnn;
            OleDbCommand cmd;
            string sql = null;
            OleDbDataReader reader;

            connetionString = "Provider=ABB OLE DB Provider for HT;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=\"\";Data Source=\"\";Location=\"\";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=\"\"";

            //OBJECTHELPER
            sql = "GET_HISTORY(OBJECTHELPER=History Log Template Dion)";

            cnn = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);

            try
            {
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, cnn);
                cnn.Open();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                Console.WriteLine("Values:");
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetName(i) + " - " + reader.GetValue(i));
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error while executing command 2 !");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: See following : https://sites.google.com/site/fixwindowsupdateerror2016/need_for_fixing_runtime_error_374#:~:text=The%20main%20reason%20for%20Runtime,will%20run%20like%20brand%20new.

Comment: @DionBartelen It looks like you posted an `exception` code. You have this wrapped in a `try-catch`, what does the exception message tell you? After a search for that `exception` code, I found this related article: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412672/when-c-sharp-program-crash-how-to-know-why)

Comment: @RyanWilson There is no exception code because the program exits with an exit code 0x0000374. I first found on google that it could be a heap memory problem but  because powershell does work i doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

After an afternoon of trying I found out that when targeting .net 4.0 the System.Data.OleDb functions as expected. All other tested versions of .net (4.5, 4.6 and 4.7.2) dit not work.